# Edit and Delete functionality is not working as Excepted

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I Have a form,when I submit the details of that form,It will redirect to next page and date will display there. There itself I have two buttons to Edit and Delete.That two Functionality is not working..
Can you help me in this?? Thanks in Advance..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

 class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             data:[],
              objEdit:obj
                   }
            }


// handleInput(e){
//     this.state.objEdit[e.target.name] = e.target.value
//     this.setState({objEdit:this.state.objEdit})
// }

handleInput(e){

    this.setState({
        objEdit:{...this.state.objEdit, [e.target.name] : e.target.value}
    })

}

updateUser = () =>{
    console.log(this.state.objEdit)
    const objEdit = {...this.state.objEdit, id: null};
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/data/", objEdit).then(()=>{
     this.props.history.push('/Form')
         }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Error Occured")
    })
} 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <div className="col-sm-4">

                    <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="fname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.fname} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="lname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.lname} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="tel">Tel</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Tel" value={this.state.objEdit.tel} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.address} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="fname">City</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.city} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="state">State</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="state" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.state} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="zip">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.objEdit.zip} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInput(e)}}/>
                    </div>    
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.updateUser}>Submit</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

                </div> 

            // </div>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

Here my Edit and Delete Function are there.I have two buttons to Edit and Delete.That two Functionality is not working..

```
 let obj={
        fname:"",
        lname:"",
        tel:"",
        address:"",
        city:"",
        state:"",
        zip:'',
        id:''
    }

    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



        class Form extends Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props)

                this.state = {
                     data:[],

                    }
                    }
                    componentDidMount(){
                        fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(user => this.setState({data:user}))
                    }
                    editUser=(obj,index)=>{
                        console.log(obj,index)
                        this.setState({objEdit:obj})
                    }
                    deleteUser=(i)=>{
                        console.log("deleteUser called",i)
                        axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/data/"+this.state.data[i].id).then(res=>{
                            console.log()
                        }).catch((error)=>{
                            console.log("Error Occured")
                        })
                    }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                 <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-8">
                            <table className="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Tel</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>Zip</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.data.map((obj,i)=>{
                                    return <tr key={i}>{Object.keys(obj).map((property)=>{
                                        return <td key={property}>{obj[property]}</td>

                                    })}<td><button onClick={()=>{this.editUser(obj,i)}} className="btn btn-info">Edit</button></td>
                                    <td><button onClick={()=>{this.deleteUser(i)}} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td></tr>
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                            <Link to ="/">  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" >Back</button></Link> 
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }
        export default Form;
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say those functions are not working? They are not being called or they behave differently.

Comment: They are being called but Once I refresh the page then only there working...But without refershing the page I need to delete..

Comment: Hi Sundeep, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Delete is a simple. As you are iterating over local state for your data, you need to delete the data from local state when you get success from `delete` `axios` call,

```
deleteUser=(i)=>{
    console.log("deleteUser called",i)
    axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/data/"+this.state.data[i].id).then(res=>{
        console.log("success");

        this.state.data.splice(i,1); //This will delete data fro local state.

    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Error Occured")
    })
}
```

Now for update you cannot directly `setState` state from some other component where you don't have any relation.

```
this.setState({objEdit:obj})
```

This cannot be done, because `objEdit` is from `App` component. You don't have any relation between `App` and `Form` component.

One way is you can pass `obj` like, (Just an idea)

```
editUser=(obj,index)=>{
    console.log(obj,index)
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname:"/",   //probablt this is for App component
        state: {objEdit : JSON.stringify(obj)}
    })
}
```

Of course you need to wrap `Form` component using `withRouter`,

```
export default withRouter(Form)
```

Now in `App` component you can get this data in `componentDiMount`,

```
componentDidMount(){
  let objEdit = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.objEdit)

  if(objEdit){
    this.setState({objEdit})
  }
}
```

Now you will get pre-filled values in your form, you just need to handle the update button functionality.

In your update function you are adding `id` manually,

```
const objEdit = {...this.state.objEdit, id: null};
```

But in this case you need to have check that if `objEdit` alreay have `id`, if yes then you need to hit the `update` API call.